# How to call a react component from html

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have define a react component that receive parameters

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import DocumentEditor from './DocumentEditor';

export default function DocumentEditorContainer(props){
    //let props = {container : "root", value: ""};
    const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById(props.container));
    root.render(
      <React.StrictMode>
        <DocumentEditor value = {props.value}/>
      </React.StrictMode>
    );
}
```

I package it using webpack, and I need to call that module from a script tag inside a html file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./aux.js"></script>
<script>
        DocumentEditorContainer("root", "123");
</script>
```

But I am getting that DocumentEditorContainer is undefined. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code snippets you've shared, it seems like you're trying to use the `DocumentEditorContainer` function from an external script in your HTML file. However, the problem is that this function isn't globally accessible because it's bundled with webpack.

When webpack bundles your code, it encapsulates your modules in closures, and thus they aren't added to the global scope. As a result, when you try to call `DocumentEditorContainer` from your script tag, it's undefined because it's not in the global scope.

To solve this issue, you need to expose your `DocumentEditorContainer` to the global scope. I've never used it in a project, but I'll give it a try, as I think it should work.

Basically, you can do this by attaching the function to the `window` object in your JavaScript file. Here's how you can do it:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import DocumentEditor from './DocumentEditor';

function DocumentEditorContainer(props){
    const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById(props.container));
    root.render(
      <React.StrictMode>
        <DocumentEditor value = {props.value}/>
      </React.StrictMode>
    );
}

// Expose the function to the global scope
window.DocumentEditorContainer = DocumentEditorContainer;
```

Now, you should be able to call `DocumentEditorContainer` from your HTML file:

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="./aux.js"></script>
<script>
    DocumentEditorContainer({container: "root", value: "123"});
</script>
```

Note that I changed the way `DocumentEditorContainer` is called. Instead of two arguments, it should be called with an object that has `container` and `value` properties, as that's what your function expects.

Remember that attaching variables to the global scope can potentially lead to conflicts and should generally be avoided if possible. In a larger application or when integrating with other libraries, it would be better to manage all of your code within the React application and avoid manual DOM manipulations and global state.

Comment: *Many* of your recent answers appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). As a heads-up, [posting of AI-generated content is not permitted on Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). 

If you used an AI tool for assistance on this answer, could I ask you to (1) Reply in a comment here confirming that it was AI-generated, along with what tool (e.g., ChatGPT, Bing Chat, Copilot, etc.) -- We're compiling data on AI-assisted answers and could use your help. (2) After commenting, I recommend deleting your answer.  Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.

Comment: I'm also a React dev, and I exactly know what I'm writing for. Is that fun @NotTheDr01ds?

Comment: For clarity, are you saying that you are not using any AI assistance when creating any of your answers here on SO?

Comment: I know answers on tools that I'm familiar with (or used in the past), and I answer them by myself

Comment: How can you provide two lengthy answers with an interval of less than 5 minutes? And before December 2022 you never (with one exception) provided more than one answer per day. It has many signals of being generated by ChatGPT or similar. [It doesn't appear to be human](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SRKjf8b4f2E&t=1m52s).

Comment: @PeterMortensen I had time over these days. And I felt I could help. But seems like I need trackrecord to provide answers, good for you on this platform